Battery drain on Ubuntu 22. Need help understanding powertop
I just bought a brand new Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Gen4. I switched to Ubuntu 22.04 and the battery life is terrible, barely 2 hrs on light usage. I ran powertop and there are a lot of entries marked Bad but I do not understand what I can do about them as a lot of them seem to be drivers. Any help is deeply appreciated!
   Bad           VM writeback timeout
   Bad           NMI watchdog should be turned off
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-12 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 7)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-5 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 0)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-7 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 2)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-9 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 4)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-11 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 6)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-4 (SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 1 at 0b20)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-6 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 1)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-8 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 3)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-10 (AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 5)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-2 (SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at 0b00)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-3 (SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 2 at 0b00)
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e8
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e9
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f1
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f0
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f6
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f2
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f3
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f5
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f4
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15bf
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f7
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1502
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c7


Please [edit] your question and add your hardware details. Especially whether this has a discrete graphics card, what driver you use with it (see inxi -G) and what CPU etc.

This tab is largely irrelevant, modern Linux kernels are good enough at powering down hardware components when necessary. Please post the output of Overview and Device Stats tabs.

@terdon his HW configuration is Googlable in under 10 seconds. https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpadt/thinkpad-t14-gen-4-(14-inch-intel)/len101t0057#tech_specs

@ArtemS.Tashkinov first of all, that's irrelevant: the information needed to answer the question should be in the question. Second, thinkpads offer configuration options when you buy them, many (although it does looks like this generation of t14 doesn't) offer the option of discrete graphics, and certainly different CPUs. And what you say about modern Linux kernels is wrong, especially with the thinkpads, both T and P14s (which I own) which actually have serious issues with overheating and battery.

My 12 year old looks the same in powertop. I wouldn't be concerned in the first place. ==> r u sure that this is measured with AC power unplugged? Suggest you head over to thinkpad wiki and read about tlp. Install tlp and post results. Machine details would be helpful as well - suggest to use inxi -Fz.
